# Bash join command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, join

Infile1:

```
1 a
3 c
4 d
6 f
```

Infile2:

```
1 a 
2 b
5 e
6 f
7 g
8 h
```

How do I join these files with the unix join command to get this output:

```
1 aa
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 ff
7 g 
8 h
```

Dogbanes answer worked but...
when I apply dogbanes answer on this file:

```
27  27
28  22
29  37
30  15
31  21
32  13
33  18
34  24
```

and this:

```
27  7
28  13
29  6
30  12
31  30
32  5
33  10
34  28
```

They don't join:

```
27  27
27  7
28  13
28  22
29  37
29  6
30  12
30  15
31  21
31  30
32  13
32  5
33  10
33  18
34  24
34  28
```

The second scenario is tab delimited so I used `-t \t`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First `sort` both files. Then use `join` to join on the first field of both files. You also need to pipe the output through `sed` if you want to remove the space and thus convert `a a` into `aa`. This is shown below:

```
$ join -t " " -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -a 2  <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sed 's/ \([a-z]\) / \1/g'
1 aa
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 ff
7 g
8 h
```

Answer (score 14):

Works for me (almost). You should specify `-t $'\t'` for the tab character, not just `-t \t`. Bash does not interpret `\t` unless in `$''` quotes.

```
join -t $'\t' -o 1.2,2.2 <(echo  $'27\t27
28\t22
29\t37
30\t15
31\t21
32\t13
33\t18
34\t24' | sort) <(echo $'27\t7
28\t13
29\t6
30\t12
31\t30
32\t5
33\t10
34\t28' | sort)
27      7
22      13
37      6
15      12
21      30
13      5
18      10
24      28
```

Answer (score 5):

this should work for your both cases:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next;} {a[$1]=($1 in a)?a[$1]$2:$2}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' f1 f2|sort
```

output for case one:

```
1 aa
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 ff
7 g
8 h
```

output for case two:

```
27 277
28 2213
29 376
30 1512
31 2130
32 135
33 1810
34 2428
```

Comment: Nicely done. Liked the use of `ternary operator` instead of `if-else` +1 :)