# Using Bash to compare columns from 2 text files as matrices

Tags: bash, matrix, text-files

I have two text files that I would like to be read in as matrices.  Matrix A (or text file A) is tab delimited and contains a latitude column, longitude column, and name column (among other things).  Matrix B (or text file B) is tab delimited and contains a latitude column, and longitude column (among other things).  I would like to read each of these in, assign names to the columns, loop through A's Latitude looking for matching ones in B, if there is a match, compare Longitude, if there is a match, write a new matrix C (text file C) that has lat, long, and name (with the other information from the column).  I don't even know how to go about reading these in and assigning names to the column values.  Is this possible?

Comment: please post sample input files and desired output.  You'll be surprised how many different solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure Bash solution, then something along these lines could do it:

```
file_a=A
file_b=B
file_c=C

while read -r lat_a long_a name_a acol ; do
    while read -r lat_b long_b bcol ; do
        if [[ $lat_a == "$lat_b" && $long_a == "$long_b" ]] ; then
            printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' \
                "$lat_a" "$long_a" "$name_a" "$acol" "$bcol"
        fi
    done <"$file_b"
done <"$file_a" >"$file_c"
```

That assumes one extra column in each of the files (`acol` in the first one and `bcol` in the second one).  It would need to be adapted to handle whatever the real columns are.

The Bash code re-reads the entire second file for every line of the first file that it reads, so it will be very slow if the files are big.

A better alternative may be to use the `join` command.  See [Bash join command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849681/bash-join-command) for examples (but note that the title is misleading: `join` is a standalone program that does not depend on Bash).